# how to build .ipa file in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

i run this command on Nativescript CLI

`tns build ios --release`

but not build `.ipa` file.

how to build `.ipa` file?

Answer (score 17):

After building with `tns build ios --release --forDevice` 
the IPA file will be located in the following folder

```
<project>/platforms/ios/build/device
```

Comment: what argument do i pass to `--forDevice`?